# bash: preserve $_ in a DEBUG trap

Tags: bash

In `bash`, the [manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters)  `$_` should be “the last argument of the last command executed”.

Here is the expected behaviour:

```
$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
$ echo $_
3
$
```

When using a `DEBUG` trap, `$_` is based upon the last command run by the trap (`date` in the example below) rather than the last command the user entered:

```
$ exec bash
$ unset PROMPT_COMMAND
$ trap date DEBUG
$ echo 1 2 3
Sat Dec  3 11:54:33 ICT 2016
1 2 3
$ echo $_
Sat Dec  3 11:54:37 ICT 2016
date
$ # User blinks in confusion and says "but I didn't just type date!"
```

It seems that by default, setting a `DEBUG` trap changes the default behaviour of `$_`.

Both [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/issues/367#issuecomment-260082109) and [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) suffer from this.

Interestingly, this works as expected in `zsh`:

```
$ zsh
genesis% trap date DEBUG
genesis% echo 1 2 3
Sat Dec  3 12:18:01 ICT 2016
1 2 3
genesis% echo $_
Sat Dec  3 12:18:04 ICT 2016
3
genesis%
```

**How can I preserve the value of `$_` when using a `DEBUG` trap?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that "the last argument of the last command executed" includes the literal text "last command executed", not "last command entered by the user"; bash is behaving as its documentation promises in this respect.

But never mind that: Unless your traps are ever returning nonzero values (and thus aborting commands they run before), this is easy enough to work around:

```
trapfunc() { local old_; old_=$1; date; : "$old_"; }
trap 'trapfunc "$_"' DEBUG
```

Comment: Any reason you're not quoting `$1`?

Comment: @TomHale Parameter expansion and word splitting doesn't happen in assignments: `a='hello world *.txt';b=$a` `b` is just fine.

Comment: Although I am ordinarily a supporter of not over-quoting and normally do not use double quotes on the RHS of assignments, I think best practice does dictate double quotes on the RHS.  It probably should be `local old_="$1";`  (To be clear, this is completely a stylistic point and has no actual impact.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I split the assignment away from the `local` declaration; less ambiguity now.