# Bash debug trap preserve custom exit value with extdebug on

Tags: bash

I'm using bash's debug trap to manipulate commands and execute them within the debug trap function, while preventing the original command from execution. 
This works by

```
shopt -s extdebug
```

The command is prevented from execution by returning a 1 from the trap. However, I want `$?` to be set to the exit status of my command. Instead, $? is always zero. Please look at the following code:

```
dbgtrap(){
    echo "command incoming: $BASH_COMMAND"
    [[ $BASH_COMMAND == 'echo $?' ]] && return 0
    (exit 97)
    return 1
}

shopt -s extdebug
trap 'dbgtrap' DEBUG

echo hi 
echo $? # this should be 97 but is 0
```

`echo hi` is not executed while my stupid custom command `(exit 97)` is (which is what I want).
The next command `echo $?` is allowed, because the trap returns 0. I want `$?` to be 97 in this scenario. Any way to do that?

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944532/bash-preserve-in-a-debug-trap) Charles Duffy answered

> But never mind that: Unless your traps are ever returning nonzero values (and thus aborting commands they run before), this is easy enough to work around:

So, I guess in this case it's not so easy - at least I haven't found a way yet. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... Your "stupid custom command" is executed in a sub-shell, but as written, your function has two possible return values, generated by `return 0` and `return 1`. These return values are used to guide the execution of commands of your script, and are not available as part of your program execution.

That said, you can record the return value of your embedded command in another variable.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dbgtrap(){
    printf 'incoming: _%s_\n' "$BASH_COMMAND"
    [[ $BASH_COMMAND == *=* ]] && return 0
    (exit 97)
    declare -g stupidreturn=$?
    echo "stupid worked: $stupidreturn"
    return $stupidreturn
}

shopt -s extdebug
trap 'dbgtrap' DEBUG

echo hi
echo return=$?
echo stupid=$stupidreturn
```

Results:

```
incoming: _echo hi_
stupid worked: 97
incoming: _echo return=$?_
return=0
incoming: _echo stupid=$stupidreturn_
stupid=97
```

The only "magic" associated with return values from the debug function are:

**0** - success
**2** - special behaviour within a subroutine (simulates a **return**)
**other non-zero** - next command is skipped.

So a value of `97` would seem to be functionally equivalent to a value of `1`, but it's *still* not made available within the normal flow of the script, and so it does not populate `$?`.

Comment: Please let me clarify: you showed me how to get the 97 WITHIN the debug trap. However, I want the 97 to be accessible outside the debugtrap by $? while having prevented the original command from executing.

Comment: @spawn - gotcha. rewrote the answer, let me know if it answers your question better now.

Comment: thanks for the rewrite. I'm sorry to say that it still does not answer the question I had in mind - as you say: "it's still not made available within the normal flow of the script, and so it does not populate $?". That's the behaviour I'm interested in.

Comment: How does "it doesn't work that way" not answer the question? I even offered a workaround, using a global variable. If what you're asking for is simply not possible, then will no answer ever be accepted?

Comment: It surely is possible, for example by hacking the memory location, where $? is stored, directly with a tool like https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh. The answer of Charles Duffy I quoted in my question above also implies that it's not impossible. Whether it is a good solution for the problem is another question.

Comment: I'm unaware of any mechanism built in to bash which is able to hack memory locations. While ctypes.sh is interesting, I would consider it third party software, and so wouldn't have recommended it as part of a solution. (You're not making a request for a tool, that would make your question off-topic.) And in the answer from Charles, the value of `$_` is set outside the trap function, and used to populate `$1` within the function. If I'm reading it correctly, that's completely different from what you're asking for. Good luck with it, anyway.